# How can I write this django query?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have the below models in django which represent articles and their sections. Articles have an order/index that represent the article's respective order in a section and sections have an order too so that they can also be sorted with other sections.

```
class ArticleSection(models.Model):
    title = CharField(max_length=50)
    order = PositiveIntegerField()  # the sections order with other sections

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Article(models.Model):
    section = models.ForeignKey(
        ArticleSection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = CharField(max_length=100)
    order = PositiveIntegerField()  # the articles order in the section its in
```

What I want to do is get a list of articles, sorted by their article order, group them by section and then finally sort by section order. So I essentially the result should look something like this:

```
{
    section4: [article1, article2, article20],
    section8: [article1, article2, article3]
    ... 
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A query is normally "flat", as in it does not contain hierarchical structures. You can however post-process the objects yourself. We can do that with the [**`groupby(..)`** function [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter

qs = Article.objects.select_related(
    'section'
).order_by('section__order', 'section_id', 'order')

result = {
    section: list(articles)
    for section, articles in groupby(qs, attrgetter('section'))
}
```

Note that although Python dictionaries use insertion order (since [python-3.7](/questions/tagged/python-3.7)), if you use a different format like JSON, that will not per se respect the insertion order in a different environment (JavaScript, etc.).

Comment: How come you're not sorting the article's order too?

Comment: Why section_id?

Comment: @ninesalt: because if two `section`s have the same `order`, we need to perform a tie-break, such that the sections occur in "bursts". Otherwise the `groupby` will fail. `groupby` has as precondition that the stream of items should appear in "packs" to group them.

Comment: aha, thats very smart. Shouldnt the id be the last field we sort on though?

Comment: @ninesalt: no, since otherwise if the `section` order is the same, and the `article` order is different it will appear in different "packs". But these can still belong to the same `section`.

Comment: Ok cool. I believe you've answered my question but do you have any idea how I can use this snippet with django rest framework? I have a serializer that serializes individual articles and I have a viewset around them, looks like this snippet is going to change everything I have.

Comment: @ninesalt: I think you will need to call the serializer on the `section` and `articles` in the dictionary comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

If btoth models will always be ordered by the same column then you can add a default ordering to each model's Meta

```
class ArticleSection(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']

class Article(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']
```